# RegEx matching 5 letters followed by ".exe"

Tags: regex

I have tried this regex:

```
^\w{5}\.(exe)$
```

which should match

5 letters followed by .exe like:

```
abcde.exe
regra.exe
```

it's not working for "samba vote files"

Where is my error in it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make it possible to help you, you should consider mentioning which language you are using (Regex standards are very different). Second, you should also mention, "what is not working"? Does it match more than 5 characters? Does it match less? Does it match anything at all? ...
Also, what is your input string looks like?
You are trying to match from beginning of line to end of line by using ^ and $. Is your string just a filename?

Comment: It works for me in python. What language are you using?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. It matches both of the examples you posted, with or without the capturing group (with all the supported Regex dialects in RegexBuddy except the two `POXIX`, the `XML Schema`, and the `XPath` engines).

Comment: i need it for samba vote and tried to test it online @ http://regexpal.com/ which failed with given test patterns.

Comment: Please update the question with these information.

Comment: @Ken White: Thx for tip for RegexBuddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(\w{5})(?=.exe$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/tY6idGRjAFTTuky8)

It matches the first letters and puts them into a capture group if its followed by a .exe but doesn't capture the .exe at all!

This will work also :)

```
^(\w{5}).exe$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/9fTe10Qb-X9p3Gj6)

- `^`  denotes the start of the line
- `\w` denotes letters, numbers, and underscores (same as `[_a-zA-Z0-9]`)
- `{5}` represents 5 characters exactly
- `$`  is the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will match `12345.exe` and even `_____.exe`, which is not your states intention.

To match 5 (lowercase) letters then ".exe":

```
^[a-z]{5}\.exe$
```

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis around `.exe` are not needed (although they shouldn't cause any error); this should suffice:

`^\w{5}\.exe$`

Example in python:

```
import re
In[1]: re.search('^\w{5}\.exe$', 'regra.exe')
Out[1]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x101f1fb90>

In [2]: re.search('^\w{5}\.exe$', 'abcdeas.exe')
Out[2]: None
```